# Is there a way to use a CSS variable as a property?

Tags: css

I don't mean using variables as only the value of the property, but as the *property itself*.

Here's a quick example to show what i'm talking about it:

```css
:root {
    --backgroundcolorproperty: "background-color";
    --backgroundcolorvalue: #fff;
}

body {
    var(--backgroundcolorproperty): var(--backgroundcolorvalue);
}
```

In this example, in place of an actual property (e.g. `background-color`) we used a variable that contained the property instead.

Now why would this be useful? I was testing this out when I was messing with margins and sizes. More specifically, I was thinking this could be useful for properties such as `max-height`/`min-height` and `max-width`/`min-width`. The max and min variations of the width and height properties can have drastically different effects, and yet they also overwrite one another (min takes priority). Like with pretty much all variables this would just be a time saver, if you have more than a few containers that you need to compare width and heights it can be quite tedious to go through and change them all. Of course you can find and replace or use Regex, but it would be far simpler to just change a variable.

When I tried to set the variable as the property using a similar example to the one above, Chrome DevTools spat out "Unknown Property Name".

Any ideas? I'm assuming this isn't currently possible.

Comment: No. If you need dynamic properties you could use Javascript.

Comment: My primary use case is CSS injection, e.g. through Stylus, not where I have full control over the source files. Of course I am aware of Tampermonkey and similar programs, but i'm not sure if it would be possible for two extensions (e.g. Tampermonkey and Stylus) to work together and reference eachother.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible with pure CSS. However, we can leverage some javascript instead if that is acceptable?

```
//get variables
const style = getComputedStyle(document.body);
const prop = style.getPropertyValue("--backgroundcolorproperty");
const val = style.getPropertyValue("--backgroundcolorvalue");

//apply them
document.body.style[prop] = val;
```

Although, to be honest, I'm not entirely sure of the benefit of this solution?